# Exporting all function addresses from IDA

Tags: ida

I have a x86 executable opened in IDA.
In the function window you can see a list of all functions with their starting address.

[image]

My goal is to programmatically export a list of all functions IDA found including the following informations:

- Their starting address
- Their instructions as a byte array

How would i do this?

Comment: Unless you are using the free version, IDA comes with built-in support for Python scripts: IdaPython https://github.com/idapython/src Soo the examples: https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/examples/core/list_segment_functions.py

Comment: Thanks those links helped as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

idc

```
auto func,i;
func = NextFunction(0);
while ( func != BADADDR ) 
{
    Message("start = %08x size = %04x    " , func , GetFunctionAttr(func,FUNCATTR_END )-func);
    for (i=0; i<0x10;i++)
    {
        Message("%02x ", Byte(func+i));
    }
    Message("\n");
    func = NextFunction(func);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks works great!